# File does not get deleted - RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making an app for displaying files from sd card using `RecyclerView`, I have also added a button to delete the files. But the problem is the `RecyclerView` gets deleted but the original file does not. Any help would be appreciated.

The code for `OnClick` Delete button:

```
 holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(String.valueOf(trackuri));
                file.delete();
                mMusic.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mMusic.size());



                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Removed : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

The code of complete class Adapter:

```
 public MusicAdapter(Context context, List<Music> music) {
    mMusic = new ArrayList<>();
    if(music != null) {
        mMusic.addAll(music);
    }
    mContext = context;
    mPlaceholder = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_music_note_black_48dp);
    // Get the maximum size of byte we are allowed to allocate on the VM head and convert it to bytes.
    int maxSize = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    // Divide the maximum size by eight to get a adequate size the LRU cache should reach before it starts to evict bitmaps.
    int cacheSize = maxSize / 8;
    mBitmapCache = new LruCache<Long, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(Long key, Bitmap value) {
            // returns the size of bitmaps in kilobytes.
            return value.getByteCount() / 1024;
        }
    };
}
/**
 * Adds a {@link Music} item to the Adapter.
 * @param
 */
/**
 * Adds a {@link List} of {@link Music} to the adapters.
 * This method replaces the current music items inside of the adapter with the specified music items.
 * @param
 */
public void clearItem() {
    mMusic.clear();
}
public void addItems(List<Music> music) {
    // Clear the old items. I only do this so that I don't have to do duplicating checks on the music items.
    mMusic.clear();
    // Add the new music list.
    mMusic.addAll(music);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(0, music.size());
}
/**
 * Clears the {@link Music} items inside of this adapter.
 */
@Override
public MusicViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    MusicViewHolder musicViewHolder = new MusicViewHolder(v);
    return musicViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MusicViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Music music = mMusic.get(position);
    holder.itemView.setLongClickable(true);
    // Check the Bitmap cache for the album art first..
    final Bitmap bitmap = mBitmapCache.get(music.getAlbumId());
    // If the bitmap is not null, then use the cached images.
    if(bitmap != null){
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else {
        // No album art could be found in the cache try reloading it.
        // In a real work example you should check that this value is not some junk value indicating that their is no album artwork.
        loadAlbumArt(holder.icon, music.getAlbumId());
    }

    holder.artist.setText(music.getArtist());
    holder.title.setText(music.getTitle());
    final Uri trackuri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, music.getId());
    final Uri turi= ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, music.getId());


    holder.button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Playrecord.class);

                                            intent.setData(trackuri);
                                            mContext.startActivity(intent);


                                        }
                                        });
    holder.button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File(String.valueOf(trackuri));
            file.delete();
            mMusic.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mMusic.size());



            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Removed : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });




}




/**
 * Helper method for asynchronously loading album art.
 * @param icon
 * @param albumId
 */
public void loadAlbumArt(ImageView icon, long albumId) {
    // Check the current album art task if any and cancel it, if it is loading album art that doesn't match the specified album id.
    if(cancelLoadTask(icon, albumId)) {
         // There was either no task running or it was loading a different image so create a new one to load the proper image.
        LoadAlbumArt loadAlbumArt = new LoadAlbumArt(icon, mContext);
        // Store the task inside of the async drawable.
        AsyncDrawable drawable = new AsyncDrawable(mContext.getResources(), mPlaceholder.getBitmap(),loadAlbumArt);
        icon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        loadAlbumArt.execute(albumId);
    }
}

/**
 * Helper method cancelling {@link LoadAlbumArt}.
 *
 * @param icon
 * @param albumId
 * @return
 */
public boolean cancelLoadTask(ImageView icon, long albumId) {
    LoadAlbumArt loadAlbumArt = (LoadAlbumArt) getLoadTask(icon);
    // If the task is null return true because we want to try and load the album art.
    if(loadAlbumArt == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if(loadAlbumArt != null) {
        // If the album id differs cancel this task because it cannot be recycled for this imageview.
        if(loadAlbumArt.albumId != albumId) {
            loadAlbumArt.cancel(true);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Helper method for extracting an {@link LoadAlbumArt}.
 * @param icon
 * @return
 */
public AsyncTask getLoadTask(ImageView icon) {
    LoadAlbumArt task = null;
    Drawable drawable = icon.getDrawable();
    if(drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
        task = ((AsyncDrawable) drawable).getLoadArtworkTask();
    }
    return task;
}

public void remove(long itemId) {
}




private class LoadAlbumArt extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, Bitmap> {

    // URI that points to the AlbumArt database.
    private final Uri albumArtURI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    public WeakReference<ImageView> mIcon;
    // Holds a publicly accessible albumId to be checked against.
    public long albumId;
    public Context mContext;
    int width, height;

    public LoadAlbumArt(ImageView icon, Context context) {
        // Store a weak reference to the imageView.
        mIcon = new WeakReference<ImageView>(icon);
        // Store the width and height of the imageview.
        // This is necessary for properly scalling the bitmap.
        width = icon.getWidth();
        height = icon.getHeight();
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(isCancelled() || bitmap == null){
            return;
        }
        // Check to make sure that the imageview has not been garbage collected as well as the
        // LoadArtworkTask is the same as this one.
        if(mIcon != null && mIcon.get() != null) {
            ImageView icon = mIcon.get();
            Drawable drawable = icon.getDrawable();
            if(drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
                LoadAlbumArt task = ((AsyncDrawable) drawable).getLoadArtworkTask();
                // Make sure that this is the same task as the one current stored inside of the ImageView's drawable.
                if(task != null && task == this) {
                    icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
        mBitmapCache.put(albumId, bitmap);
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Long... params) {
        // AsyncTask are not guaranteed to start immediately and could be cancelled somewhere in between calling doInBackground.
        if(isCancelled()){
            return null;
        }
        albumId = params[0];
        // Append the albumId to the end of the albumArtURI to create a new Uri that should point directly to the album art if it exist.
        Uri albumArt = ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtURI, albumId);
        Bitmap bmp = null;

        return bmp;
    }
}
/**
 * Custom drawable that holds a LoadArtworkTask
 */

private static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    WeakReference<LoadAlbumArt> loadArtworkTaskWeakReference;

    public AsyncDrawable(Resources resources, Bitmap bitmap, LoadAlbumArt task) {
        super(resources, bitmap);
        // Store the LoadArtwork task inside of a weak reference so it can still be garbage collected.
        loadArtworkTaskWeakReference = new WeakReference<LoadAlbumArt>(task);
    }

    public LoadAlbumArt getLoadArtworkTask() {
        return loadArtworkTaskWeakReference.get();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMusic.size();
}

/**
 * Custom ViewHolder that represents the List Item.
 */
public static class MusicViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView icon;
    TextView title;
    TextView artist;
    Button button8;
    Button deleteButton;

    public MusicViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        artist = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        button8 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button8);
        deleteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: whats the values of  `trackuri`

Comment: in the Adapter class in OnBindViewHolder class

Comment: ` final Uri trackuri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, music.getId());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete like this

```
  mContext.getContentResolver().delete(trackuri,null, null);
```

**Update:** use this with `file.delete();` not alone

```
 mContext.getContentResolver().delete(trackuri,null, null);

    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
```

Comment: it removes it from cache of the view but, when restarted device everything comes back as it is. The file does not gets deleted from sdcard

Comment: bhai solved it, turned out that I was passing uri instead of file path. Thank you so much.